# How to check if a file have been complete and reach to EOF?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, eof

My collaborator was processing a large batch of files, but some of the output files seem to be interrupted before they were completed. It seems that these incomplete files do not have the end of the file character (EOF). I would like to do a script in batch to loop through all of these files and check if the EOF character is there for every one of the ~500 files. Can you give me any idea of how to do this? Which command can I use to know if a file has EOF character at the end?

I am not sure if there is supposed to be a special character at the end of the files when they are complete, but normal files looks like this

```
my_user$ tail CHSA0011.fastq
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@HS40_15367:8:1106:6878:29640/2
TGATCCATCGTGATGTCTTATTTAAGGGGAACGTGTGGGCTATTTAGGCTTTATGACCCTGAAGTAGGAACCAGA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@HS40_15367:8:1202:14585:48098/1
TGATCCATCGTGATGTCTTATTTAAGGGGAACGTGTGGGCTATTTAGGCTTTATGACCCTGAAGTAGGAACCAGA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
my_user$
```

But when I do `tail` tho thse interrupted files they look like:

```
my_user$ tail IST-MES1.fastq
@HS19_13305:3:1115:13001:3380/2
GTGGAGACGAGGTTTCACCATGTTGGCCAGGCTGGTCTCGAGCTCCTGACCTCAAGTGATCCGTCTGCCTTGGCC
+
@B@FFFFFHHHHFHHIJJJJJIIJJJJJJJIJJJJGIIJJGIIGIIJJJJFDHHIJFHGIGHIHHHFFFFFFEEE
@HS19_13305:3:1106:5551:75750/2
CGAGGTTTCACCATGTTGGCCAGGCTGGTCTCGAGCTCCTGACCTCAAGTGATCCGTCTGCCTTGGCCCCCCAAA
+
CCCFFADFHHHHHJJIJJJJJJJJJJJJEGGIJGGHIIJIIIIIIJJJJDEGGIJJJGIIIJJIJJJHHHFDDDD
@HS19_13305:3:2110:17731:73616/2
CGAGGTTTCACCATGTTGGCCAGGCTGmy_user$
```

As you can see, in normal files my_user$ is displayed one line below the end of the file. But in these interrupted ones my_user$ is next to the end of the files. Maybe it just because the file does not end with a line breaker `\n` ?

I am sorry if the question is a bit confusing,

cheers,
Guillermo

Comment: There's no such thing as an end-of-file character. End-of-file means just that: you have reach the end of the file, and there's nothing left to read. Likely you are getting an error because whatever is processing the files *expected* there to be more to read, and there simply wasn't.

Comment: An EOF error is something that a parser usually produces when, for example, it thinks it needs to read 4 bytes from the file but there are only 3 left. It's *not* indicating that there was a specific EOF character that it expected to see but did not.

Comment: @chepner thanks for your comment, but there is something special about these files then, because when I do `tail` the file does not like it has a proper finish. I will update the question to show you.

Comment: If these are intended to be POSIX text files, then every line, including the last, is required to be terminated by a linefeed. It's not an EOF character, though, because it's no different than any other linefeed terminating previous lines. Seeing a linefeed by itself doesn't signal the end of the file, but seeing a linefeed with nothing else *after* it does.

Comment: CP/M, then DOS, and so even windows define an EOF character. If those files are coming from DOS, then a missing EOF (char number 26) can signify that the file is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the difference is because in the first case the file ends with `\n` (new line).

```
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
my_user$
```

In this case it doesn't have a new line so the next thing it prints is your use (actually your `PS1`)

```
CGAGGTTTCACCATGTTGGCCAGGCTGmy_user$
```

You can try this:

```
echo "CCCFFADFHHHHH"      # <--- implicitly includes newline at the end

echo -n "CCCFFADFHHHHH"   # <--- does not include newline at the end
```

There are actually two endline options, `\r` and `\n` and there are different standards according to your OS. I will assume you are working on linux and only `\n` is used. So in this example the newline character is `0x0a` (number 10) in the ascii map.

If you want to know the last char of each file, you can do:

```
echo -n "CCCFFADFHHHHH" > uglyfile.txt
echo  "CCCFFADFHHHHH" > nicefile.txt
for file in *.txt; do 
    echo -n "$file ends with: 0x"; 
    tail -c 1 $file | xxd -p;
done;
```

If you want to know which files end with a char that is not a newline, you can do:

```
echo -n "CCCFFADFHHHHH" > uglyfile.txt
echo  "CCCFFADFHHHHH" > nicefile.txt
for file in *.txt; do 
    lastchar_hex=`tail -c 1 $file | xxd -p`
    if [[ $lastchar_hex != '0a' ]]; then
      echo "File $file does not end with newline"
    fi;
done;
```

Comment: Awesome! I will try this. Thanks a lot :) -  and yes I only work with linux/unix so you assumed well.

Comment: It worked very nicely. It seems that we have a lot of interrupted files, but now we are going to be able to fix this, thanks!

Comment: @Geparada Be aware that this check is not guaranteed to find all interrupted files --  it's entirely possible for a file to happen to be interrupted at the end of a line, in which case it'll look normal by this test. It'd really be better to get the length (in bytes) of the original files, and compare to the lengths of your copies.